# Howto Track down variable Corruption

Tags: visual-studio-2008, winapi, mfc, corrupt

I have a MFC class derived from CStdioFile declared as follows

```
// Datafile.h
class CDataFile : public CStdioFile
{
 public:
 CDataFile(void);
 ~CDataFile(void);

 int OpenFile(LPCWSTR FileName);
}
```

After my OpenFile function is called the FileName variable is being corrupted.

```
int CDataFile::OpenFile(LPCWSTR FileName)
    {

m_OpenFlags = CFile::modeNoTruncate | CFile::modeReadWrite;   

// Before open. FileName = "c:\afile.txt"

     if (!Open(FileName, m_OpenFlags, NULL)) 

         {
            return GetLastError();
         }

//After open. FileName = ""ﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮﻮވĚᗸ÷ᘸ÷㼠碞­"

// other stuff
}

}
```

But if I change the FileName to

```
WCHAR FileName[] = _T("c:\\afile.txt");
```

Before opening the File the variable Filename remains untouched.  I have seen this behaviour before with the MFC/Winapi and always worked around it be by using character arrays instead of LPCWSTR or CString.    Why does this happen? and what is the best way to track down problems such as this with the VS Debugger.  The corruption appears to happen here in the MFC file Filecore.cpp

```
if (!CFile::Open(lpszFileName, (nOpenFlags & ~typeText), pException))
  return FALSE;
```

Comment: The (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwbccf8z.aspx) says it needs LPCTSTR not LPCWSTR (normal char vs wide string). Maybe that is the issue?

Comment: I dont think so "typedef LPCWSTR LPCTSTR;"

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at using a [data breakpoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/greggm/archive/2004/04/30/124161.aspx) (also known as a hardware breakpoint.)  You can break when the memory is modified.